# file-get-contents: don't stop script when warning occurs (Redirection limit reached)

Tags: php, function

I have a php script like that:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
foreach ($csvarray as $product){
   $url = $product[31];
   $html = file_get_html($url);
   ...
}
```

One URL has a redirection problem, so it redirects more than 20 times.
So I get this warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http:/...)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Redirection limit
>   reached, aborting in ... on line ...

Unfortunately, the other URLs of my csvarray don't get processed, because the script stops after this URL wih the redirection problem.

How can I just ignore this warning and continue with the next urls?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `CURL` instead of `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: file\_get\_contents: failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164196/warning-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-redirection-limit-reached-ab)

Comment: No that's a different problem!

Comment: How is it different? OP there has the same error that you have.

Answer (score 2):

> *Unfortunately, the other URLs of my csvarray don't get processed, because the script stops after this URL wih the redirection problem.*

Your script doesn't stop because of the [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) `redirection limit reached` error. `file_get_contents()` triggers `E_WARNING` which is non-fatal error and **doesn't halt script**.

My guess is that your script stops because of the maximum execution [time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or any other error. Put `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(-1);` on the beginning of the file your call.

---

> *How can I just ignore this warning and continue with the next urls?*

#### 1. The easiest/noobish solution is to just ignore error with `@` prefix.

```
$html = @file_get_contents('http://bit.ly/6wgJO');
```

#### 2. You can increase/descrese max redirects for `file_get_contents()` with 3rd parameter `$context` ([context options and parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php)) :

```
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['max_redirects' => 50]]);
$html = @file_get_contents('http://bit.ly/6wgJO', false, $context);
```

#### 3. Other solution of hiding errors is `ignore_errors` in context options :

```
$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['max_redirects' => 0, 'ignore_errors' => true]]);
$html = file_get_contents('http://bit.ly/6wgJO', false, $context);
```

#### 4. Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

- You can do magic with cURL.
- Set option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true` or `false` if you wish to follow redirects.
- You can even set option `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` for number of maximum redirects to follow.
- Set option `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` for maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

See other options [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Answer (score -1):

Run the function with `@` prefix:

```
$html = @file_get_html($url);
```

Should solve the problem.

You can use `cURL` and set a parameter called `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `TRUE`.

Answer (score -3):

there are several ways you can do this one would be to try to catch the exceptions

```
try {
$html = file_get_html($url);
}catch(Exception $e){
//Do what you want to do with the code
}
```

another way would be to simply suppress the warning by using @ in front of file_get_html:

```
$html = @file_get_html($url);
```

There are better ways of handling this error as well if you want to know more but those are the simplest ones.

Comment: I think that `file_get_contents()` function doesn't throw exceptions. Correct me if I am wrong.