# get html code from aspx page with php?

Tags: php

i need to get html souce code from aspx page,as example can use [Go daddy link](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/website-builder.aspx?ci=88060)

I have tried cURL and file_get_contents bui it dons't work.
Tried cURL with setting user agent.
file_get_contents shows Redirection limit reached!

```
$url = 'godaddy.com/hosting/website-builder.aspx?ci=88060';
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36 OPR/22.0.1471.40 (Edition Next)"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
$result=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 
echo "Results: <br>".$result;
```

Comment: What you exactly want is not clear...

Comment: i want to get html code from .aspx pages

Comment: This question is off-topic since the OP did not do any research on his own.

Comment: I have tried cURL and file_get_contents bui it dons't work

Comment: Broken Heart and  Y U NO WORK and others if u think u can vote down question even dont ask the problem,ur more stupid then me

Comment: maybe you need to post the codes of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get just the plain html of that particular site. You can use `file_get_contents()` on this one and then use `htmlentities()`. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://ph.godaddy.com/hosting/website-builder.aspx?ci=88060';
$contents = htmlentities(file_get_contents($url));
echo $contents;

?>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kSo6EO)

Comment: thats what i tolked about,ty

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is viewing the already processed output as html and css.

Right Click -> View Source

However, you won't be able to see the ASPX source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use CURL to read the remote URL to fetch the HTML.

```
<?php
$url = "http://godaddy.com/hosting/website-builder.aspx?ci=88060";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output=curl_exec($ch); 
echo $output;
?>
```

[How to get Content ot Remote HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733876/how-to-get-content-ot-remote-html-page)

Comment: I have tried this,file get contents show redirect limit reached,with this one code above shows blank page with words Object moved here!

Comment: Use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option as shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164196/warning-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-redirection-limit-reached-ab

Comment: i tried this one too,same Object moved to here.