# How to get meta tags in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to export the below url meta tags but it is not working it giving below result
Warning: get_meta_tags(https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/white-house-reels-as-fbi-director-contradicts-official-claims-about-alleged-abuser/2018/02/13/f010f256-10d9-11e8-9570-29c9830535e5_story.html?tid=pm_pop): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in.
Any ideas for this ?

Comment: uh, maybe cause the url is broken ?

Comment: It's not. Did you try it?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164196/warning-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-redirection-limit-reached-ab

Comment: no url is working fine but its meta tags is not get exported.

Comment: 3 mins ago the browser said that secure connection couldn't be established and visiting http:// version ended with 403 error, however it works now

Comment: @azjezz Any idea how I can export meta tags of the this url ? It showing the warning and no meta tags get exported.

Answer (score -1):

For start you need to make a call to the 1st page to set the cookie else it's not going to work

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.washingtonpost.com");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$cookieName = "";
if(isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])){
    $cookieName = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
}
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/logs/'.$cookieName.'.txt'); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/logs/'.$cookieName.'.txt');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

then a second call to get the actual page

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/white-house-reels-as-fbi-director-contradicts-official-claims-about-alleged-abuser/2018/02/13/f010f256-10d9-11e8-9570-29c9830535e5_story.html?tid=pm_pop");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$cookieName = "";
if(isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])){
    $cookieName = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
}
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, LOG_DIR.'/'.$cookieName.'.txt');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, LOG_DIR.'/'.$cookieName.'.txt');
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

and finaly with DOMDocument we parse the dom tree

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$siteData = new DOMDocument();
$siteData->loadHTML($page);

$metaElements = $siteData->getElementsByTagName("meta");
if($metaElements->item(0)==null){
    echo "ERROR";
}

$meta = array();
for($i=0;$i<$metaElements->length;$i++){
    $meta[$i] = array();
    for($j=0;$j<$metaElements->item($i)->attributes->length;$j++){
        $meta[$i][$j] = array($metaElements->item($i)->attributes->item($j)->name,$metaElements->item($i)->attributes->item($j)->value);
    }
}
print_r($meta);
```

meta are stored in the $meta array

you can beautify this code by organizing curl to function.