# Why does wget on the command line work, but file_get_contents does not?

Tags: php, wget, file-get-contents

I am trying to download the contents of an html file to my Ubuntu Linux 16.04 computer using php's get_file_contents() function. However, when I do this, I get this Warning:  "failed to open stream: the  , aborting"

Yet when I use wget on the terminal command line, it quickly downloads the file contents.

So why does file_get_contents not work for this? Here is my php code, which produces the Warning:

```
$testDownload = file_get_contents("https://ebird.org/region/US-AL-001?yr=all");

echo $testDownload;
```

On my Ubuntu terminal command line, here is my bash code, which works quickly and flawlessly:

```
wget https://ebird.org/region/US-AL-001?yr=all
```

I want to use php because I want to automate the downloading of a number of files and need a fair bit of code to do it, and I feel much more comfortable using php than bash.

P.S. I tried various "context" solutions for the file_get_contents function that were suggested on Stack Overflow, but they did not solve the problem.

P.P.S. I earlier tried cURL and got the same redirects Warning, though I admit to not knowing much about cURL.

Comment: Maybe cou should give curl another try with the CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS option https://stackoverflow.com/a/31704183/1152471

Comment: `print_r($http_response_header);` would enlighten you as to the reason. Bypassing a login scheme is too broad for this question/showcased prior effort. Consult with the hoster and their [TOS](https://ebird.org/science).

Comment: I followed a suggestion on Stack Overflow to use the "context" option of file_get_contents to set max redirects to a higher number than default 20. I set it to 101. Still got the redirects warning.

Comment: Re: getting enlightenment via print_r($http_response_header), I did get some enlightening information from wget. It showed "302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://ebird.org/login/cas?portal=ebird [following]", which is a redirect. What I don't understand is why wget went ahead and successfully downloaded the file, whereas file_get_contents was stymied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: the shell_exec() function in php allows me to use bash's wget command line function within my php script. I tried it and it worked. (I will have to change the ownership of the downloaded files to get access to them.) Here is the code that worked:

```
$output = shell_exec('wget https://ebird.org/region/US-AL-005?yr=all');
```

I still don't understand why wget can get the file contents but file_get_contents cannot. But with shell_exec() I have found a php solution to complete my task, so I am happy.